# How to customize the UISearchBar style

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

Does anyone know how to customize the UISearchBar style? There are 3 default styles of the UISearchBar, but I want to customize other aspects of the search bar, such as its image, background. If there is no way to do that can I use the UITextField to replace the search bar's function?

Thanks All

Answer (score 6):

As you discovered, you can customize a bar such as a search bar with the barStyle property and these two values:

UIBarStyleDefault
UIBarStyleBlack

Alternatively, you can choose a custom color for the bar using the tintColor property:

```
// use RGB values between 0.0 and 1.0
UIColor *barColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]; 
searchBar.tintColor = barColor;
```

In either case, you can make the bar translucent by setting the translucent property to YES.

Comment: If i want to replace by the image, is it ok??

Comment: You can not use an image for the background of the standard bars.

Comment: what can i do for my custom search bar?

Comment: Have you investigated the new appearance stuff in iOS 5?

Answer (score 1):

UISearchBar is a subclass of UIView, therefor you can simply add an UIView on top. (You just have to keep the area of the actual searchbar transparent.)

// Edit

It's easier if you add the image to the background (between the background and the search field, that is). To do this just add it and iterate over the subview to send the original background to the back (behind your image view).

```
searchBarOverlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchBarBack"]];
searchBarOverlay.frame = CGRectMake(-8, -2, 320, 48);
[searchBar addSubview:searchBarOverlay];
[searchBar sendSubviewToBack:searchBarOverlay];

for (UIView *v in [searchBar subviews]) {

    if ([NSStringFromClass([v class]) isEqualToString:@"UISearchBarBackground"]) 
    {
        [searchBar sendSubviewToBack:v];
    }

    if ([NSStringFromClass([v class]) isEqualToString:@"UIImageView"] && v != searchBarOverlay) 
    {
        [searchBar sendSubviewToBack:v];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For UISearchBarStyleProminent:

1) Be sure to check the "Translucent" box for the search bar in the Attributes Inspector.

2) Add the following to viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO; // If navBar
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = NO;
```

In order to get the minimal search bar to not be translucent I have put together a workaround.

1) Be sure to check the "Translucent" box for the search bar in the Attributes Inspector.

2) Add the following code to viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = NO;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor desiredColor];
```

3) A UIView needs to be added to the viewController. This view needs to be 20px heigh and should have the same color as the

```
searchBar.barTintColor.
```